Netsuite search showing different results
I made a search that is pulling a conversion rate if an opportunity was made into a sales order. I was able to pull the sales order amount just fine. However my conversion rate is off and I am stumped as to why.
Any help is appreciated.
My code
If i remove the first and third formulas the conversion rate shows up fine.
Even drilling down shows one. No idea where the system is pulling like it says four.
Drill down
